# (C++) Create dynamic global array/vector that can be accessed from functions

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, dynamic, size

I'm writting code for a dungeon game. The dungeon is a plain squared array of characters. In the actual version, the size of the array and the number of enemies and so forth are declared with "#Define", but I wanted to improve the program a bit and **let the user set** the height, width, number of enemies... 
The problem is I don't know how to declare the array in a way the size is input by the user and at the same time, the array is **global** and can be accessed by all of the functions I wrote using (#define).
I'm open to any suggestion that doesn't  involve rewriting all functions :)

**At the moment, the declaration of the array is:

```
    #define WIDTH  20
    #define HEIGHT 20
    char dun[HEIGHT][WIDTH];
```

**Link to the code : https://github.com/Zashuiba/The-Dungeon-Game/blob/master/Dungeon/Dungeon.cpp

Comment: And what is wrong with the [standard `vector` class](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)?

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <vector>
```

You may want to use `std::vector` class for that. This is a quick draft code:

```
size_t width = 20;
size_t height = 20;
std::vector< std::vector<char> > dun;

void init_array()
{
    dun.resize(height);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < height; ++i)
        dun[i].resize(width);
}
```

Comment: Okay, I have to admit that I kind of love you :) . It works perfectly, now, could you explain what "size_t" and "resize" mean?

Comment: size_t is the type for an unsigned integer of the size of you architecture (same size as a pointer).

"std::size_t can store the maximum size of a theoretically possible object of any type" (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t)

Comment: `resize` dynamically allocates the array in the heap. If you don't do this, the array has 0 elements and accessing will generate a segmentation fault (access to an illegal address).

Answer (score 0):

Make dun a vector of vectors

```
#include<vector>

std::vector<std::vector<char>> dun; //global variable

//In your input function
input_from_user()
{
    int Height = getHeight();
    int width  = getWidth();
    dun.clear();
    for(int i = 0 ; i < Height ; ++i)
    {
        std::vector<char> createdVector(Width);
        dun.push_back(createdVector);
    }
}
```

Now you can use dun as you were using the 2 dimentional char array as subscript operator is overloaded for std::vector